# How do I delete elements that are visible under Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a WP page using the Astra theme.

I edit it using Elementor.

I have 2 lines in my page, and it took me very long to find out where they come from.

[image]

If I delete all elements with Elementor, I can still see the lines, so they must be part of the underlying page.

How would I remove them?

[image]

Thank you!

Edit:

I think I found what @Mtxz meant, it's under Global->Colors:

[image]

Change the image position does change the position of the lines.
But when I click "Remove Image", nothing happens: The lines stay there, so I wonder why they are still there.

Comment: Do you have a test URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a background image on your body:

[image]

Try to see if you can find body settings or related.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me where I could look for this setting? I guess it would be a css file, right? Would that be somewhere in "Apperance->Theme file editor"? Unfortunately I don't see any way to search for a string in all files in the WP admin panel. Thank you again!

Comment: I have edited my post with some new findings. Can you tell me what you think why the lines still don't go away even if I press "Remove Image"? Btw, If I choose a different image instead, the other image is shown, and the lines disappear. But for some reason, it seems impossible to remove the lines.

Comment: It's hard to say without having access to the backend and code. Depending on how your site is built: it could come from customization plugin settings (check in plugin admin pages), in the theme appearance menu, or directly in the page template (or template part) used. Is the CSS code "printed" in the HTML (it seems so from your screen): it mostly comes from plugin/theme stuff (still, you can check template files to be sure).

Comment: Thank you very much. Please give me some time to investigate it further, ok?

Answer (score 3):

as per @Mtxz said without any access to the site we can't tell you where it's coming from. but for temporary if you want to hide rather than replace then you can use the below CSS.

Add this CSS to your active theme style.css file.

```
body, .ast-separate-container {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Or you can add this CSS using the `wp_head` action hook. add this below code to your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_css(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

        body, .ast-separate-container {
            background: none !important;
        }

    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_css', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Please give me some time to investigate it further, ok?

Comment: @tmighty sure please take your time let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: I would like to select Mtxz's answer because he was quicker and answered the question more directly. However, your answer is very valuable, too. Could you keep it? It provides great details.

Comment: @tmighty sure, no problem. my only concern is that my answer helps you.